# Recuperar data eliminada de una tabla en postgresql

Tags: postgresql

esperando que se encuentren bien, en la empresa que trabajo me preguntaron si se podía, recuperar la data eliminada de una tabla  en postgresql, estos no cuentan con un archivo de respaldo, se podrá recuperar dicha información, si es posible me podrían indicar cómo por favor. La versión de postgresl es 9.5. muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Si no has realizado un vacuum o el autovacuum no he hecho de las suyas puedes recuperar algo con esta extensión [pg_dirtyread](https://github.com/df7cb/pg_dirtyread), si necesitas un ejemplo en español puedes consultar [este](https://anthonysotolongo.wordpress.com/2016/04/04/leer-filas-borradas-o-actualizadas-en-postgresql/)